# targeting changing attributes with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have not been able to sketch this up in a jsfiddle, but here is the general concept. You have a container with a multitude of content, all have different components. How would you target the same attribute of the individual content if that attribute is different for them all. Here is a simple example:

*You would like to have all content that has a height greater than x to be in column1 and a height smaller than x in column2. You can't use a simple if **$('#content').height() > x** because that wont work since it will use the first child for content*

Is there a way to manipulate content like that with jquery?

Comment: Yes, it's called iterating ?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the DOM like this :

```
var x = 200;
$('#content').each(function(){
    if($(this).height() > x)
    {
        //Do what you want
    }
});
```

Comment: and if there is a very large amount of content, like over 10k divs, This would not be laggy or what not. I am not too familiar with the .each() event

Comment: If you have 10k of elements to move or resize, it should be done durring the page construction, server side.